# Get Address of Actual Function LoadLibraryExW Not Stub LoadLibraryExWStub

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to get the address of a function in a DLL `LoadLibraryExW`. However, when I try to get the address for this function I actually get the address to a `LoadLibraryExWStub`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

intptr_t getFuncAddr(const char* func, const char* dll)
{
    return (intptr_t)GetProcAddress(
        GetModuleHandle(dll),
        func);
}

int main()
{
    // Actual address: 000007FEFD28B2B0 Stub address I get instead: 0x00000000771d5680
    intptr_t loadLibExWAddr = getFuncAddr("LoadLibraryExW", "kernel32.dll");

    printf("%x\n", (int)loadLibExWAddr);
}
```

Assembly of those functions from Visual Studio:

```
LoadLibraryExWStub:
00000000771D5680 EB F2                jmp         LoadLibraryExW (0771D5674h)  
00000000771D5682 8B D6                mov         edx,esi  
00000000771D5684 E9 1F DC FF FF       jmp         ConstructKernelKeyPath+58h (0771D32A8h)  
00000000771D5689 8B CE                mov         ecx,esi  
00000000771D568B E9 29 DC FF FF       jmp         ConstructKernelKeyPath+69h (0771D32B9h)  
00000000771D5690 41 89 1C 24          mov         dword ptr [r12],ebx  
00000000771D5694 E9 B3 DC FF FF       jmp         ConstructKernelKeyPath+0FCh (0771D334Ch)  
00000000771D5699 90                   nop  
00000000771D569A 90                   nop  
00000000771D569B 90                   nop  
00000000771D569C 90                   nop  
00000000771D569D 90                   nop  
00000000771D569E 90                   nop  
00000000771D569F 90                   nop  

LoadLibraryExW:
000007FEFD28B2B0 FF F3                push        rbx  
000007FEFD28B2B2 56                   push        rsi  
000007FEFD28B2B3 41 54                push        r12  
000007FEFD28B2B5 48 83 EC 60          sub         rsp,60h  
000007FEFD28B2B9 45 33 E4             xor         r12d,r12d  
000007FEFD28B2BC 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
000007FEFD28B2BE 41 8B F0             mov         esi,r8d  
000007FEFD28B2C1 81 E6 00 20 00 00    and         esi,2000h  
; it's pretty long... but you can tell it's the core function that actually goes out and loads the DLL
```

In the assembly for `kernel32.dll` I also see another function named `LoadLibraryExW` which is defined as the following:

```
LoadLibraryExW:
00000000771D5674 FF 25 CE 80 08 00    jmp         qword ptr [__imp_LoadLibraryExW (07725D748h)]  
00000000771D567A 90                   nop  
00000000771D567B 90                   nop  
00000000771D567C 90                   nop  
00000000771D567D 90                   nop  
00000000771D567E 90                   nop  
00000000771D567F 90                   nop
```

This just confuses me even more. How can their be two `LoadLibraryExW` functions?

So, to reiterate I want to get the function address for that core `LoadLibraryExW` function that actually does the DLL loading; not all that other stuff that just seems to jump to it.

Comment: Impossible. What you are getting is what the DLL exports, not what you want.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Hm, well that may explain the "duplicate functions" thing but I still don't know why resolving the address of `LoadLibraryExW` gives me the address of `LoadLibraryExWStub`. And further, how I can get the "actual" address of `LoadLibraryExW`.

Comment: As said, all you get is a map of the DLL Name -> Symbol. That symbol may be anything, not related with the actual function which may have the same name. What do you need it for anyway. Hotpatching?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Oh, thank you, I see now. And yes, pretty much although I didn't know that term for it. So, now that I know there is no way to get the "actual" address of `LoadLibraryExW` with the symbols exported by the DLL how might I go about getting that "actual" address for hotpatching? I assume it would be by something pretty hacky. I know you said "all you get" but there must be some way, otherwise, how would any hotpatchers even work?

Comment: Since all applications linking to LoadLibraryExW will actually get the stub, hotpatching the stub should work, unless there is an application that knows the internal address of the actual function (most probably, a Windows dll). For hotpatching, you can use my [library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043089/HotPatching-Deep-Inside).

Comment: @OverloadedOpeator - hotpatching code must analyze instruction and have minimum disassembler. so here no problem - if hotpatch code view jump (short) it - go to the address of jmp

Comment: @RbMm Right, but with an approach like that how would I know when I've reached my desired function of the "actual" of `LoadLibraryExW`. As you can see, in the `LoadLibraryExWStub` function there is more than just one `jmp`. I could try to fingerprint `LoadLibraryExW` perhaps on its arguments and return type but that's imperfect. Of course, I could in this specific case just tell my program that the first jump leads to the actual `LoadLibraryExW` and to just disregard the next three jumps to `ConstructKernelKeyPath` in `LoadLibraryExWStub` but that sounds rather delicate and won't scale.

Comment: @OverloadedOpeator - for what you "actual" (? what is it ?) address. you simply do patch. all. not forget that all anotther - got the **same** address as you.

Comment: There is only one jmp, those other instructions are never executed and are not even part of that function most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little history lesson is helpful when explaining this.

Windows 95 only had normal exported functions and NT3&4 probably had some [forwarders](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=30473). The low-level Win32 functions lived in kernel32, user32 and gdi32 and that was that. NTDLL was supposed to be completely undocumented and off limits.

During the Vista-era Microsoft conducted an experiment known as [MinWin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinWin) which led to changes to the layering of certain components. Some function implementations mostly or fully moved to the new kernelbase.dll in Windows 7.

The Win32 ABI and millions of applications of course depend on `LoadLibraryExW` being in kernel32 so a simple stub function still exists there. **The name of the function is still `LoadLibraryExW` but the symbols often have a Stub suffix in their name** because the function does little/no work before it jumps to its new home. Windows 7 also added the [API Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets) "feature" which is supposed to make these types of changes easier in the future by not tying a function to a specific .dll.

A hooking library should not be surprised by this. Forget the symbols and focus on `GetProcAddress` and the address it returns. From a ABI perspective, it has always been legal for a function to start with a `jmp` and any type of trampoline/hooking library must be able to handle it.

If you only care about applications conforming to the documented API then you might as well do IAT hooking instead. If you want to hook "everything" then `LoadLibrary*` is never going to be deep enough.

Note: The core of the loader is actually in NTDLL, `LoadLibrary*` on NT based systems never performs the actual loading. Real security software should probably catch image sections in the kernel instead if you want to be notified about loaded modules.

Note: `jmp qword ptr [__imp_...]` is usually a call to a function in another .dll. This makes sense because `000007FEFD28B2B0` in your dump is most likely not in kernel32.

Comment: Thank you @Anders for this valuable historical insight. I was only pulling the function from `kernel32.dll` because the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw#requirements) said that is where it lived. I suppose with this in mind, the simple approach seeing as I'm just looking to patch the DLL for this program (and based on the point of my last comment on the main thread) would be to detect the platform and based off of that get a direct reference to `LoadLibraryExW` by either using `kernel32.dll` or `kernelbase.dll`.

Comment: @OverloadedOpeator - in documentation say only that *LoadLibraryExW* exported from *kernel32.dll* (what you mean under lived ?) and it really exported. as single jump in your case. this and can be forward export too like *HeapAlloc* for example (unclear why here jmp instead forward export). but all this not play role - *any type of trampoline/hooking library must be able to handle it* . and all another components, which call get proc address for `LoadLibraryExW` - got the same address as you. so this is and real address of api. jmp or another instruction - nothing change

Comment: @OverloadedOpeator kernelbase is not used by normal applications that follow the official API, they all use kernel32 on all Windows versions.